# How to insert a dictionary values to sql table?

Tags: python, sql

Consider the following dictionary where key is a string. (my dictionary contains 100s of tuples as follows, i need to insert all records)

```
 dbDic[key1]={'FuelGrade': '4', 'Delivery': '7285.000', 'UpdateFlag': 0, 'Date': '2019-06-26 00:00:00', 'SiteCode': '4198', 'FileName': 'Invoices_201906251400.csv'}
```

The SQL string being used is :

```
 sql = 'INSERT INTO [dbo].[SEDeliveryTemp] VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)'
```

I have to pass the values from my dbDict but my dbDict contains values as a sub dictionary. How can I pass the arguments to the string?

I have tried running the following code:

```
cursor.execute(sql,dbDict.values())
```

It gives me the error.

```
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('The SQL contains 6 parameter markers, but 1 parameters were supplied', 'HY000')
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you provide a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: @Ratha, please give the relevant information, in this case the structure of SEDeliveryTemp. Also, how are you trying to insert the parameters.

Comment: Shouldn't you be inserting for specific key and put cursor.execute in a loop?

Comment: @SANTOSHKUMARDESAI, I just want to pass values, not the keys. Table columns are same as values

Comment: You need to prepare your placeholders as required for the batch insert.
Like this for 3 rows:
`sql = 'INSERT INTO [dbo].[SEDeliveryTemp] VALUES ( (?,?,?,?,?,?),  (?,?,?,?,?,?),  (?,?,?,?,?,?))'`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL multiple inserts with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13020908/sql-multiple-inserts-with-python)

Comment: `cursor.execute(sql,list(dbDict.values()));` for python3

Comment: @ManthanTilva , In that case, how python matches values with right column data?

Comment: @ratha, python doesn't do that. you need to make sure by updating db schema OR passing manually while creating query string.

Comment: @ManthanTilva can you provide an example for //passing manually while creating query string. //?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to sort the `dict` values based on the table list.

**Ex:**

```
tables = ["Id", "SiteCode", "FuelGrade", "Date", "Delivery", "FileName", "UpdateFlag" ]
values = {'FuelGrade': '4', 'Delivery': '7285.000', 'UpdateFlag': 0, 'Date': '2019-06-26 00:00:00', 'SiteCode': '4198', 'FileName': 'Invoices_201906251400.csv'}

values = [i[1] for i in sorted(values.items(), key=lambda x: tables.index(x[0]))]
cursor.execute(sql, values)
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the size of the dictionary, if I were you I would use *pandas* library and *DataFrame*. I would create a DataFrame object from the dictionary, then insert the DataFrame into sql table using built-in to_sql() method. Here is an example;

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(name_of_dict)

engine = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://user:passwd@host:port/name').connect()
df.to_sql('name_of_table', con=engine, if_exists='replace')
```

This is a fast solution for large sets of data. (based on my personal experience, I haven't made any measurements)

Answer (score 0):

I have modified my code as follows based on Rakesh answer;

```
def insertToTempTable() :
    sql = 'INSERT INTO [NEO_DB].[dbo].[SEMobilDeliveryTemp] VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)'
    conn = connectDB()
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    tables = ["Id", "SiteCode", "FuelGrade", "Date", "Delivery", "FileName", "UpdateFlag"]
    for key in dbDict.keys():

        values = [i[1] for i in sorted(dbDict[key].items(), key=lambda x: tables.index(x[0]))]

        cursor.execute(sql, values)

    conn.commit()
```